# html.actionlink take C# variable as parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 <% foreach (var item in Model) { %>

        <table width="100%" class="topicContainer">
           <tr>
             <td>  <%: Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.headerclob) %></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td><%: Html.ActionLink("ViewTopic", "ViewTopic","Forum" ,
               new { id=item.topicId },null) %></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

       <% } %>
```

I want of link ViewTopic `item.headerclob` should be displayed in hyperlink without using Razor.

I also want to apply css to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the below code should work

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("item.headerclob, "ViewTopic","Forum" ,
               new { id=item.topicId },null) %>
```

it use the following format

```
public static string ActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
                                string linkText,
                                string actionName,
                                string controllerName,
                                object values, 
                                object htmlAttributes)
```

if you are using MVC 3 then the you can just use "item.topicId" instead of "id = item.topicId"

**Edited**
    yes it works but after removing semicolon from item.headerClob

```
    <%: Html.ActionLink(item.headerclob, "ViewTopic","Forum" ,
               new { id=item.topicId },null) %>
```

**Edit**
add a class to action link then use your css file for setting necessary properties

```
<%: Html.ActionLink(item.headerclob, "ViewTopic","Forum" ,
                   new { id=item.topicId , @class = "YourClass"},null) %>
```

now you can apply css properties to the action link you set css properties to others

**EDIT**
If you do not want to use razor, I could suggest you to build anchors by your self like following

```
<a href="<%=Url.Action("ViewTopic", "Forum",new { id=item.topicId})%>" class="YourClass"> item.headerclob </a>
```

Comment: yes it is a slight mistake I just saw it. must have mistakenly typed the double quotation. please mark this as answer if this helps thank you

Comment: how to apply css to Html.ActionLink

Comment: I dontwant to use razor syntax

Comment: @prerna - that's not razor syntax, that's webform syntax